# find_or_create on a has many through relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, has-many-through

I have a has many through relationship in my app:

**Shows** has many **Bands** through => **Lineups**

**Bands** are unique by :name

```
class Show < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :city_id, :title, :dateonly, :timeonly, :image, :canceled, :venue_attributes, :bands_attributes

  belongs_to :city
  belongs_to :venue
  has_many :lineups
  has_many :bands, through: :lineups
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end


class Lineup < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :show
  belongs_to :band


end


class Band < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :website, :country, :state
  has_many :lineups
  has_many :shows, through: :lineups

  validates :name, presence: true
  validates_uniqueness_of :name
  before_save :titleize_name

  private
    def titleize_name
      self.name = self.name.titleize
    end

end
```

New Bands are created like this:

(lets say we have a show record already saved called s1)

```
> s1.bands.new(name: "Wet Food")
> s1.save
```

Right now this will only save if a band named "Wet Food" doesn't already exist

In which model is the best place to do a Band.find_or_create in this relationship so that an existing band can be used if one with the same name exists?

Comment: where will you use an existing band by using Band.find_or_create ? and try to use Band.where(name: 'Wet Food').first_or_create instead of Band.find_or_create.

Comment: lineups contains the band_id's so I guess there?

Comment: so lineup is akin to a performance, a band does one per show. a show has multiple performances per show.

Comment: Yes, I will rename it to that, it makes more sense. Thanks!

Comment: If you want to use then use like: 

s1.bands.where(name: 'Wet Food').first_or_create.

Comment: kuldeep, in which model would I put that?

Answer (score 19):

This is generally the type of call that would go in a `Controller` (or maybe a service object), but not in a `Model`.  It really depends on the particular user flow that you're trying to accomplish in your app.  Basically, where ever you are already using `s1.bands.new`, you could use this instead :

```
s1.bands.where(name: 'Wet Food').first_or_create
```