# Rails 5: Nested forms and existing associated objects

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, activerecord

I'm relatively new to Rails so please forgive me if this turns out to be quite a naive question. :]

I have two models that can be tagged: `Collection` and `Video`. I support this via a `Tag` model with a polymorphic association, and a `has_many :through` association to `Tagging`. All this works perfectly.

What I'm having a hard time figuring out is how to set up the views to accommodate this. I know that if I were only creating or updating tags that are uniquely associated with a single model then I could use a simple form and add `accepts_nested_attributes_for` to my model, but the problem I'm having is that I want to first check for the existence of a tag, and only create it if it doesn't exist, otherwise just associate the existing tag with the *new* video or collection. Obviously I could do this manually in the controller, but since Rails provides a mechanism for creating and updating associated objects automatically, I wondered if it provided anything similar for associating existing objects?

Also, I'm not sure whether I should nest the `tags` resource and handle this centrally in a `TagsController`, or whether I should manage the tags from the owning object's controller, for instance `VideosController`.

Any help or advice will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you need to do it manually, it's not that much code.

[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19469002/find-or-create-on-a-has-many-through-relationship)

Basically, you'll need `find_or_create_by` in your controller ([doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-find_or_create_by)) and `fields_for` ([doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-fields_for)) in your Collection and Video views.